# jquery mobile reverse style on mouse up

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with custom buttons in jquery mobile.

```
<li><a href="about.php">Button</a></li>
```

I want to change the background of the list element when the link button is pressed and then change it back when released.

I have tried various bits and pieces but i get theses issues:

- using vmouseup and vmousedown to change css works but when i am scrolling over them with my finger they register the event even though i have not clicked the link
- using tap stops the issue when scrolling over but it only changes the css for the down state, then the next page loads, when i go back to the first page the down state style is stile active

I hope this makes sense, the docs are just a blur to me now.

- Basically i need to style an anchor when i touch it, then reverse the style when i stop touching it.
- This needs to happen before the next page loads.
- When my finger is scrolling the screen and slides over the anchor i don not want it to register as a touch and change the style

It seems like it should be easy but i don't whats going on anyway.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

**UPDATE:**

hey finally got a combination working, not sure if i tried this last night and was just too tired to register or weather i was just to tired to miss it but i got it working using click to change style then tap to change back.

```
$(function() {
$('.profile-list li a').on( 'click', function () {
// change .css()
  });

$('.profile-list li a').on( 'tap', function (){
// change back
 });
});
```

Comment: What device are you using? All devices I know interpret touching as a "click" and moving the finder as dragging the page around...

Comment: using iOS, i have used click, when i click it changes the style but then redirects with no change back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('.profile-list li a').on( 'click', function () {
// change .css()
 });

$('.profile-list li a').on( 'tap', function (){
// change back
});
 });
```